# Need to get row value from datatable in JS in LWC, but unable to get it

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable, lwc-dom

I have simple datattable where i am displaying couple of columns ,on click of any row in datatable i need to get the value from Name column to JS for further processing

```
<template>
<lightning-datatable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        key-field="id"
        onrowselection={getNameRowData}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

JS -

```
getNameRowData(event) {
    const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
    console.log('selectedRows>>'+selectedRows);
}
```

but i am not able to see any logs printing in console.Please help
i dont want checkbox ,just when i click on any row then that perticular opp Name needs to get in JS

[image]

Comment: Please visit this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319299/lightning-web-component-can-we-catch-rowclick-event-lightning-datatable-just-cl

Comment: I guess the above solutions are when we click on checkbox of that row.Is there any way we can click on that row anywhere and we can capture the data in js instead of clicking checkbox?