# Onclick row in Datatable LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wrapper-class, onclick

Hi guys :) I am new in programming and salesforce.

I want to get to the apex and take a name of click company can you tell me what schould I wite in field `message = 'NAME OF CLICK COMPANY';`. When i am clicking on it I have just toast communicate from message.

I know the question is realy stiupid but please be tolerative I am new person in this crazy world :)

Example i found: [Lightning Web Component: Can we catch rowclick event lightning-datatable just click](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319299/lightning-web-component-can-we-catch-rowclick-event-lightning-datatable-just-cl)

[image]

**JS**

```
import { wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllCompanys from '@salesforce/apex/StockMarketSharesWrapper.getAllCompanys';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class stockMarketShares extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getAllCompanys, {}) companys;




  columns = [{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' }, { label: 'Ticker', fieldName: 'Ticker' }]


  title = 'Sample Title';
  message = 'NAME OF CLICK COMPANY';
  variant = 'error';

  showCompanies = false;

  showSearchResults() {
    this.showCompanies = true;
  }

  handleClickRow(){
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: this.title,
        message: this.message,
        variant: this.variant,
        

    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);


  }

 
  
messageToast(event){
this.message = event.target.value;
}


}
```

**APEX**

```
public with sharing class StockMarketSharesWrapper {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Wrapper> getAllCompanys(){
   
       

        // Define the list
        List<Wrapper> com = new List<Wrapper>(); 


        // Create account sObjects
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'U';
        w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
        Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
        w1.Ticker = 'UAL';
        w1.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
        Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
        w2.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
        w2.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
        Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
        w3.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
        w3.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;

        // Add accounts to the list
        com.add(w);
        com.add(w1);
        com.add(w2);
        com.add(w3);

        return com;
    }

    public class Wrapper{

@AuraEnabled
public String Name {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Ticker {get; set;}

} 

}
```

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-datatable if:true={showCompanies} onclick={handleClickRow} hide-checkbox-column data={companys.data} columns={columns} key-field="Name"></lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE, there is no `onclick` action for `lightning-datatable` .  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation .. instead you can use `onrowaction` but again it gives entire row details.