# Click event for URL column in Lightning-Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I need help with LWC.

```
<template>
<div class="slds-card__body">
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        data={tableData}
        columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

So in columns i have one with URL type. And i need to have an event or something to get Id of row when user clicks on  that URL field. so how can i do that? please help.

Comment: what you can do is you can create link as button variant as base which is look same as link and on button click you can get the id of that record.

Comment: Does this post Answer your query - [Lightning Web Component: Can we catch rowclick event lightning-datatable just click](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319299/lightning-web-component-can-we-catch-rowclick-event-lightning-datatable-just-cl) ?

Comment: thank you, @KaranSharma , i didn't think about it but it's a good idea

Comment: @SubratSrivastava yes right

Answer (score -1):

Following the above comment , To get the Id of the **row** when the user **clicks on the URL field** in the **lightning-datatable**, you can use the **onrowaction event** in the lightning-datatable.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
<template>
<div class="slds-card__body">
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        data={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

In the **handleRowAction method**, you can access the selected row by accessing the detail property of the event and then retrieve the Id of that row. You can then use this Id as needed. In the below example, I have simply logged it to the console for demonstration purposes.

```
<script>
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api tableData;
    columns = [
        //... your other columns
        { 
            label: 'URL', 
            fieldName: 'URL_Field__c', 
            type: 'url', 
            typeAttributes: { 
                label: { fieldName: 'Name' },
                target: '_blank' 
            }
        }
    ];

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const row = event.detail.row;
        const rowId = row.Id;
        // Use the rowId as needed
        console.log('Row Id: ', rowId);
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this works. It opens the url and does not invoke the handleRowAction() method for me.